# Exercise 1.1.4 in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, star-shaped

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

The following is Exercise 1.1.4 in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*:

> A subspace  $X\subset \Bbb R^n$ is said to be **star-shaped** if there is a point $x_0 \in X$ such that, for each$x \in X$ , the line segment from $x_0$ to $x$ lies in $X$.
>
> Show that if a subspace $X\subset \Bbb R^n$ is locally star-shaped, in the sense that every point of $X$ has a star-shaped neighborhood in $X$, then every path in $X$ is homotopic in $X$ to a piecewise linear path , that is , a path consisting of a finite number ofstraight line segments traversed at constant speed.show this applies in particular when $X$ is open or when $X$ is a union of finitely many closed convex sets.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $p: [0,1] \to X$ be a path. Consider the set $$\{t \in [0,1]: \text{there is a piecewise linear path from $p(0)$ to $p(t)$}\}$$

Is it open or closed?